# Calling a function from a different class

Tags: php

I am trying to solve this issue but I could not. I think I called the function incorrectly. Also I would like to know the difference between Custom::generate($r1, $p1, $a1) vs Custom::generate.

interesting is I have this code  `$c = $this->install();` in the same file but different function and it is working. I am confuse. Please help how to resolve this error

Custom.php :

```
class Custom {
  private function install() { 
  // code
  }

 public function generate($r1, $p1, $a1) {

 // code
 $c = $this->install();

 }
}
```

MotherUpdate.php

```
protected function exeGen() {

$template = Custom::generate($r1, $p1, $a1);

}
```

I got this error :

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Using $this when not in object context in /Users/amin/Custom/Custom.php:12
```

Comment: `generate()` is not a static function. You need to instantiate the `Custom()` class as `$class = new Custom()`. Then `$class->generate()`

Answer (score 1):

As per my comment,

`generate()` is not a static function. You need to instantiate the `Custom()` class before accessing the `generate()` function.

You access static function using the `:` eg. `Custom::function()`

What you should do is instantiate the `Custom()` class and then call the `generate()` function

```
protected function exeGen() {
//instantiate Custom Class
$custom = new Custom();
$template = $custom->generate($r1, $p1, $a1);    
}
```

Also when using static functions, you shouldn't use `$this` inside it.

Answer (score 1):

You need either this

```
class Custom {
    public static function generate($r1, $p1, $a1) {
        // You can't use $this here
    }
}

$template = Custom::generate($r1, $p1, $a1);
```

Or this

```
class Custom {
    public function generate($r1, $p1, $a1) {
        // You can use $this here
    }
}


$custom = new Custom();
$template = $custom->generate($r1, $p1, $a1);
```